# School of Witchcraft and Wizardry Transfers

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

> Can students transfer from one school of witchcraft and wizardry to another?

I am aware that there are [many schools of witchcraft and wizardry](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wizarding_school) and I'm aware of the fact that they enroll students based on their geographical range, as well as the decision made by The Educational Office of the International Confederation of Wizards, when it comes to foreign and overseas students.

But what if one student, who was learning in Hogwarts, decides to move to Durmstrang Institute? Is this allowed by the Ministry? Or is there a syllabus difference that makes transfers cumbersome?

Comment: The student might need to be obliviated before transferring, since some schools (eg, Durmstrang in *Goblet of Fire*) keep their locations secret even from students of other schools.

Comment: Wasn't aware this was asked earlier. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there is a syllabus difference that makes transfers cumbersome.

When evil forces took rule of Hogwarts, they completely changed the syllabus (introduced previously forbidden Dark Arts with forbidden spells like Crucio).
It was the decision of one of the wizarding schools. So, any other schools can simply change their syllabus and make transfers too hard. But maybe it is possible to hire private teachers who help transfer, but not to the same year, but to the lesser

Comment: Is there any evidence that a student transfer ever took place?

Comment: @VarunNair Rand al'Thor gave link to the questions which can answer to your question (in the comment to this question)